# Spring Boot, Spring Security - Pass current logged in user details from one micro-service to another micro-service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using 2 microservices. One is for UI (Web + API) and another one for the backend service(REST API). And using Feign Client to connect from UI to the backend API.

Now I need to pass the current logged in user details from the Web service to the backend API service.

I am getting the user details using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails().

What is a good way to pass the user details? I need user details in all the API endpoints for auditing.

Is it good to pass user details using @RequestParam?

Comment: request header will be a better choice if you could send user details in a secured token.

Comment: @Ritesh thanks for the suggestion. I had this choice earlier, but want to check any other available options.

Comment: no problem. In general, communication from one microservice to another is a sign of a design problem.